# Error parsing data .Value String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: java, php, android, json

Here is list activity

ListActivity:

```
public class ListDataActivity extends ListActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_listview);

    url = "http://xxx.xx.x.xxx/index.php";

    Bundle c = getIntent().getExtras();
    blo = c.getString("blood");

    new ProgressTask(ListDataActivity.this).execute();

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();

}

class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> jsonlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    {
        if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "INTERNET CONNECTION NOT PRESENT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            startActivity(new Intent(ListDataActivity.this,
                    MainActivity.class));
        }

    }


    public ProgressTask(ListActivity activity) {
        context = activity;
    }

    private Context context;

    protected void onPreExecute() {}

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(context, jsonlist,
                R.layout.row_listitem, new String[] { name, Category },
                new int[] { R.id.vehicleType, R.id.vehicleColor }) {

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                    ViewGroup parent) {

                if (convertView == null) {

                    // This a new view we inflate the new layout

                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_listitem,
                            null);
                }

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (position % 2 == 1)
                    convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(120, 151, 66));
                else
                    convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(86, 107, 129));

                return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            }
        };

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        lv = getListView();

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
            }
        });
    }

    protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {
        url = url + "?blo_name=" + blo;
        Log.d("", url);

        baseAdapter jParser = new baseAdapter();

        JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

        if (json != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {

                try {
                    JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(i);

                    String vtype = c.getString(name);
                    String vfuel = c.getString(Category);

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // Add child node to HashMap key & value
                    map.put(name, vtype);
                    map.put(Category, vfuel);

                    jsonlist.add(map);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;

    }
```

Base Adapter class:

```
public class baseAdapter {

static InputStream iStream = null;
static JSONArray jarray = null;
static String json = "";

public baseAdapter() {}

public JSONArray getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("==>", "Failed ");
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Parse String to JSON object
    try {

        jarray = new JSONArray(builder.toString());

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON Object
    return jarray;

}
```

PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['blo_name'])) {
    $str = $_POST['blo_name'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM blood_group where Category IN ($str)";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))  
        $output[]=$row;
    print(json_encode($output));
    mysql_close();
}
```

I am trying to parse `bol` string, it have value like `bol="'B-','O-'";` while I parse this type of value it didn't show results and gives the logcat
logcat:

```
Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

I need to get result against query `SELECT * FROM blood_group where Category IN ($str)` but I cannot get. When I give hard core value in php like `$str = "'A+','B+'";` it give me result while parsing from android it does not give result while in logcat I can see value `http://xxx.xx.x.xxx/heart.php?blo_name='A','B'` but error as well.

Comment: Post Response from server or Log `builder.toString()`

Comment: First of all this is bol="'B-','O-'" not JSONArray is string and this bol=["B-","O-"] is JSONArray.

Comment: sorry i didn't get what u say..

Comment: @user3671508 Post your Server Response.

Comment: What you getting in JSON

Comment: try to print/log you **builder.toString()** to check whatever you have received is as per your expectation or not?

Comment: did not get anything in logcat while try this way responce = builder.toString(); and then Log.d("", responce);

Comment: @SillentKilleri have tried this one and getting value like same way 'A+\'...

Comment: @user3671508 then you should update the question instead of asking 3 question with same query.

Comment: @SillentKiller yup u r right,i will follow next.

Comment: can i get possible solution please..

Comment: after getting the response from server print it in log and check the response at http://jsoneditoronline.org it will help yourself to detect the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

Notice `<br` - the web service is returning HTML and not a plain JSON string. Basically you need to fix your PHP response so it doesn't return HTML.

Comment: i am new in it , didn't have much ideas. can u explain please..